# What is forwarding ref in react and How we use it and why we use it.?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I am new in react, I see the term (forwarding ref). I have good knowledge of useRef() hook , ref attribute and useState() hooks. But I listen this term and I read articles for forwarding ref but unfortunately I dont get idea what is it actually, and why we use it, where we use and how it will use in project. I am working with functional component in react so I want to know about there usage for functional component. Anyone help me , explain me here in simple way.

Comment: Standard dom elements support refs, such as `<div ref={someRef} />`. Custom function components do not, unless you tell react what that ref is supposed to point to. `forwardRef` is how you tell react what it points to.

Comment: Check this article, it explains what's a point of using ref forwarding: https://felixgerschau.com/react-forwardref-explained/

Basically, it's passing ref into the child component, so child component can initialize it with ref to some of its DOM elements, so parent component (one which passes ref) can do something with this ref (with DOM element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref forwarding is a technique for automatically passing a ref through a component to one of its children.

This can help creating reusable compoenents, such as if we want to get hold of a button component and want to do something with it , we can pass the reference to the button DOM element.

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

Reference
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html